# Matlab anonymous function list arguments

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I'm rather new to anonymous functions, and I couldn't find anything via a google search, so I'd thought I'd come here for help. For a symbolic function, I can use `symvar` to determine the function dependencies. Is there an equivalent for anonymous functions?

EXAMPLE:
This function tells you how to turn water into gold

```
afun = @(temp,pressure,volume,time,mass) ...
```

Aside from `disp(afun)`, is there a way to capture the dependent variables with a function like `symvar` where the input variable listing can be stored in another variable? For example test = symvars(afun) where symvar is replace by something relating to anonymous functions. In other words, I'd like "test" to be an array equal to "temp,pressure,volume,time,mass"?

Comment: ...or like `coeffnames(f)` from `cfit` objects....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "anonymous" in anonymous function doesn't refer to the contents being unknown. It refers to the fact that this function *does not have a static name* like a function within an m-file.

For example, if you create the following function, it can *only* be used by it's name, `myfunction`.

```
function out = myfunction(a,b)
```

With a function handle, however, it is assigned to a variable and that *variable's* name is used to call the function.

```
myfunc = @(a,b)disp('I am a walrus');
myfunc2 = myfunc;
```

Now the *same* function can be called using *either* `myfunc()` or `myfunc2()`.

Now that we've gotten the nomenclature out of the way, if you are given a function handle, you can actually just display the function handle (using `disp`) and see the function definition (complete with input arguments).

```
f = @(a,b)disp('I am a sneaky function');
disp(f)

    f = @(a,b)disp('I am a sneaky function');
```

From this it's easy to infer that `f` takes two input arguments (`a` and `b`).

As far as what these input arguments should be and what that function *does* with those arguments, you'd have to look at the function component of the function handle or ask whoever created it. If you can't tell, this doesn't make it "anonymous", it just makes it poorly documented.

Most function introspection functions that would work on a regular function will *also* work on an anonymous function if you want to get information about the input arguments programmatically.

```
%// Get the number of input arguments
nargin(f)
```

## Update

If you used `matlabFunction` to generate an anonymous function from a symbolic expression, you can specify the input arguments in the call to `matlabFunction` [using the `Vars` input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#input_argument_namevalue_vars).

As an example [from the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#bul8wgx-1).

```
syms x y z t
r = (x + y/2 + z/3)*exp(-t);

%// The first input argument will be t and the second will be an array of [x,y,z]
matlabFunction(r, 'Vars', {t,[x y z]});
%// @(t,in2)exp(-t).*(in2(1)+in2(2).*(1.0./2.0)+in2(3).*(1.0./3.0));
```

Or as another example where I use an *array* rather than a cell array containing the values. They will then all appear as separate inputs to the anonymous function by name.

```
syms x y z
r = x + y/2 + z/3;
matlabFunction(r, 'Vars', [x,y,z]);
%// @(x,y,z)x+y.*(1.0./2.0)+z.*(1.0./3.0);
```

If you do not specify them, MATLAB automatically chooses the order as specified in the documentation:

> By default, when you convert symbolic expressions, the order is alphabetical. When you convert symbolic functions, their input arguments appear in front of other variables, and all other variables are sorted alphabetically.

## Update 2

If you *really* want some way to inspect the input variables of an anonymous function, here is a little anonymous function to do that for you.

```
anoninputs = @(f)strsplit(regexp(func2str(f), '(?<=^@\()[^\)]*', 'match', 'once'), ',');
```

Now we can test it like:

```
f = @(a,b)disp('Just another function. Do not mind me');

anoninputs(f)

    'a'   'b'
```

Comment: Yeah, that just gives `in2` which is an array of arguments. Again, had I not known anything about the function, how would I know what those arguments are. I guess that's just the nature of "anonymous" functions in that they truly are anonymous. To work with them, you have to know something about the function or meaning of the inputs.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack "To work with them, you have to know something about the function or meaning of the inputs." That's true of any function.

Comment: That function is still anonymous in that it doesn't have a name. :)

Comment: @TroyHaskin Good point. I'll add that detail to the explanation of the name.

Comment: @TroyHaskin That's kinda the point of the question. An anonymous function has to be built at some point  by someone. Now say that function was given to you, and you knew nothing about the expression, but you knew it solved a particular problem given inputs (a,b,c,d,etc). If I `disp` the function, it gives `@(a,in2)`, where `in2` is an array of input arguments. This would contain (b,c,d,etc). Clearly I can find the number of arguments, but I'm assuming the order matters. When the function is built, using `matlabFunction`, shouldn't it keep track of the `vars` definition upon creation?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Please see the update in my answer on how to use `matlabFunction` properly

Comment: @Suever With regards to your update, that's exactly what my question is about. Does the anonymous function remember what `Vars` is (order, name)? Or would I have to save what `Vars` is in a separate variable to know the input arguments and the order?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Sorry my last example was incorrect, it should be an array not a cell of the values, then the names themselves are used as the inputs. Also it is clear that you haven't read the documentation because I just posted the line from the documentation that explicitly states what the input arguments are if they are *not* specified.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Also regarding your edit to your post. You completely control (yourself) what the order of inputs is. And you're also calling your function. So, shouldn't you know what they are? Also use an array instead of a cell array and you will be able to see the inputs with `disp`.

Comment: @Suever I will make another edit and remove my knowledge of the problem

Comment: @Suever OK....the answer was hidden in your comment..."Also use an array instead of a cell array and you will be able to see the inputs". And, yes, I probably should have paid closer attention to the documentation, but who has time for that : ) Thanks for the input!!

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Ok I will add that to the question and example at the end to be a little more explicit.

Comment: @Suever I accepted the solution to early. While you did clear up the `disp` part of it, is there a way to capture the variables with a function like `symvar` where the input variable listing can be stored in another variable? For example  test = symvars(afun) where `symvar` is replace by something relating to anonymous functions?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack I just wrote you a function which will accomplish that for you. It's in the "Update 2" section

Comment: @Suever That was _really_ what I was after. My program builds anonymous functions with each iteration, and the input variables are constantly changing. To work with the function, I needed to know which variables to pass in (from within the script, not display). It was either "ask the function which ones you need", or create another variable to track and carry the information. I honestly thought it would be something as simple as `symvar`, but I guess not. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Now understanding what you wanted, I'll just add that a simple mechanism doesn't exist for this because that's not really a robust or efficient way to typically program something. The argument order is best when it is fixed (or dynamically known) and symbol independent with the function itself adapting to vary arities. That's not a judgement; just an explanation.